# Does anyone have the Scott Allen's ChartBuilder class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mschart

I am trying to use the Scott Allen's ChartBuilder class, but I can't find it anywhere, I tried googling and go through a guide, but it links to msdn page which doesn't exist anymore

Does anyone still have that class?

Comment: check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd453008.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I tried downloading that source, but its gone

Comment: "Code download avaliable from the MSDN gallery"

Comment: yeah sorry , i realized that .. but you can still use that code listed in that page and he has mentioned directions also on how to implement ..

Comment: Just ping him on Twitter @OdeToCode

Comment: Ah, thank you :) - Don't use twitter much so totally forgot about that :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: 
You can download the project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13430676/Charting.zip

Long answer:
The download was lost during one of the dozen or so redesigns, reorganizations, and upgrades of the MSDN web site, team, and magazine staff. I've tried to let them know, and also tried to fix this myself. Unfortunately, fixing the link seems to require a GUID value which is unknown to me, and GUIDs turn out to be notoriously difficult to guess. I'll keep trying, but in the meantime I've put it up for download from my Dropbox account.

Hope that helps...

Comment: That exactly what I needed! Thank you very much :) Your Pluralsight video's and MSDN articles help me alot :)

Comment: I had a dream last night that this was the GUID you were looking for: 6737b9e6-41e8-47b7-9676-9e9f9459b4e8 P.s. Thanks for the link :-)

Comment: I second Reigo about your videos and articles. Thanks for the Charting class and for all the cool stuff you're doing in/for the programming community.